# Bootstrap nav bar and Rails 5 malfunctioning, only in mobile production version.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, navbar

Everything is working perfectly when I view the local Rails app through Chrome dev tools testing for mobile responsiveness. I deployed my code through AWS, and it also works fine when I view the web version of the site. I only have issues when I view the site on an iphone or ipad.

When I scroll down, certain elements seem to be getting stuck or caught in the navbar. I've attached a screenshot here. 
 [I've attached a screenshot here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAZ68.png)

I've tried removing the svg elements on the page because that's the elements that seemed to be causing the issue, but that didn't work.

index.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDiv" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stephanie Dacre</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDiv">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Work</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#connect" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Connect</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<div id="particles-js">
</div>
<h1 class="banner">Hi, my Name is Stephanie.<br>
I build websites.
</h1>

<div class ="container-fluid bg-white" id="about">
  <h1 class="about title spin">About</h1>
  <div class="row section-info">
   <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 profile-desc">
      <p class="profile-title icon"><%= image_tag ("codinphoto.png"), :class => "profile-icon"%> Me</p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><span class="underline--magical">  I'm a full stack web developer located in Victoria BC.<br></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><span class="underline--magical">  I love Ruby on Rails, & UX/UI.<br></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><span class="underline--magical">  I also love running, cats, plants & coffee.<br></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><span class="underline--magical">  I'm currently looking for a full time position in a growth centric company.<br><br></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span><span class="underline--magical">  In the meantime, I'm freelancing!<br><li><a href="#connect">Lets create something together.</a></li><br></span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 icon" id="center">
      <h1>Stack</h1>
      <div class="skillBox wow bounceInLeft">
        <p>HTML5</p>
        <p>80%</p>
          <div class="skill">
            <div class="skill_level" style="width: 80%">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skillBox">
        <p>CSS3</p>
        <p>70%</p>
        <div class="skill">
          <div class="skill_level" style="width: 70%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skillBox">
        <p>Javascript & Jquery</p>
        <p>60%</p>
        <div class="skill">
          <div class="skill_level" style="width: 60%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skillBox">
        <p>Ruby on Rails</p>
        <p>75%</p>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="skill_level" style="width: 75%">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skillBox">
        <p>React</p>
        <p>50%</p>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="skill_level" style="width: 50%">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class ="container-fluid bg-orange" id="work">
  <h1 class="about title spin">Work</h1>
  <div class="row section-info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card1.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
      <div class="middle">
      <a href="http://www.chasecontractingltd.com/" target="_blank"><div class="text">Chase Contracting <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card2.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
     <div class="middle">
      <a href="https://marineartbydale.com/" target="_blank"><div class="text">Marine Art by Dale <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card3.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
      <div class="middle">
      <a href="https://elementalcolour.com/" target="_blank"><div class="text">Elemental Colour <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></div></a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row section-info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card4.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
      <div class="middle">
      <a href="https://nogungang.com/" target="_blank"><div class="text">No Gun Gang <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card5.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
      <div class="text middle">COMING SOON
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 card">
    <%= image_tag ("card6.jpg"), :class => "card image"%>
      <div class="middle">
      <a href="http://www.gledstoneupholstery.com/" target="_blank"><div class="text">Gledstone Upholstery <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class ="container-fluid bg-white" id="connect">
  <div class="title about spin">Connect
  </div>
  <div class="row section-info">
    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
    </div>
    <div class="collab col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">Collaborations<br>
      <span class="bigger">&</span> Questions
    </div>
    <div class="connect-info col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">I am available for freelance projects and full-time employment.<br><br>
      Stephanie Dacre<br>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>: stephdacre@gmail.com<br>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>: 250-505-4654<br>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <svg width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 114 114" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
        <polygon id="path-1" points="0 0 113.386 0 113.386 113.386 0 113.386"></polygon>
        </defs>
          <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="instagram-glyph">
                    <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                        <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                    </mask>
                    <g id="Shape"></g>
                    <path d="M100.136,47.884 L90.282,47.884 C91,50.671 91.424,53.583 91.424,56.594 C91.424,75.832 75.832,91.424 56.597,91.424 C37.363,91.424 21.77,75.832 21.77,56.594 C21.77,53.583 22.196,50.671 22.914,47.884 L13.059,47.884 L13.059,95.777 C13.059,98.178 15.009,100.127 17.417,100.127 L95.778,100.127 C96.9327527,100.128061 98.0406314,99.6703552 98.857915,98.8545719 C99.6751987,98.0387885 100.13494,96.9317527 100.136,95.777 L100.136,47.884 Z M100.136,17.411 C100.13547,16.2558088 99.6759948,15.1481565 98.8586824,14.3317819 C98.0413701,13.5154072 96.9331911,13.0572041 95.778,13.058 L82.72,13.058 C80.3157427,13.0579999 78.3665522,15.0067427 78.366,17.411 L78.366,30.474 C78.366,31.6286607 78.8247556,32.7360148 79.6413177,33.5523894 C80.4578799,34.368764 81.5653394,34.8272653 82.72,34.827 L95.778,34.827 C96.9331911,34.8277959 98.0413701,34.3695928 98.8586824,33.5532181 C99.6759948,32.7368435 100.13547,31.6291912 100.136,30.474 L100.136,17.411 Z M56.596,34.827 C44.573,34.827 34.828,44.571 34.828,56.594 C34.828,68.615 44.573,78.364 56.596,78.364 C68.619,78.364 78.366,68.615 78.366,56.594 C78.366,44.571 68.619,34.827 56.596,34.827 Z M100.136,113.192 L13.058,113.192 C5.847,113.192 -7.10542736e-15,107.343 -7.10542736e-15,100.126 L-7.10542736e-15,13.058 C-7.10542736e-15,5.846 5.847,-7.10542736e-15 13.058,-7.10542736e-15 L100.136,-7.10542736e-15 C107.348,-7.10542736e-15 113.194,5.846 113.194,13.058 L113.194,100.126 C113.193,107.343 107.348,113.192 100.136,113.192 Z" id="Shape" fill="#231F20" mask="url(#mask-2)"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
      </svg>: @codingnomad<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit">This site was built with <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span> & Rails by Stephanie Dacre</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Codingnomad</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style'%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'particles', 'app'%>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.scss:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require particles.js
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The library seems to be not right ordering in `application.js` follow the below ordering

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require particles
//= require_tree .
```

And here is removed `//= require rails-ujs` because you can consider one like if you use `jquery_ujs` then you don't need `rails-ujs` see [this](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-the-jquery-rails-gem)